# Topic based pub/sub for JS

Tags: javascript, wildcard, publish-subscribe

I want to be able to have a pubsub mechanism similar to found in jQuery's custom events and PubSubJS (http://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS).

The problem is that each one of these pubsub libraries does an exact match on the subject. IO want to be able to publish a subject like:

```
"Order/Sent/1234"
```

And have a listen subscribe to either:

```
"Order/Sent/1234"
"Order/Sent/*"
"Order/*/1234"
```

Does anyone know of anything like this for JS?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the one you like.  Fork it on github, go open `pubsub.js` and do something like:

```
var deliverMessage = function(){
    var subscribers = [];

    for(var n in messages){
        if( new RegExp('^' + n + '$').test( message ) ){
            subscribers = subscribers.concat( messages[n] );
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

You'll probably need to modify that a bit, do something like replace all `*`'s with `.*` or `[^\/]*` before converting to a regex, etc...

Comment: This approach makes sense and is one that I considered, but I wonder if there is a way of doing it more efficiently. Depending on the number of subscribers there are this could be really inefficient. I was hoping that if there was already a solution they had solved this inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Paytm's turbo churged Publish - Subscribe Library

export const PaytmConnect = (() => {
  const topics = {};

  return {
    subscribe: (topic, listener) => {
      // Create the topic's object if not yet created
      if (!topics.hasOwnProperty(topic)) topics[topic] = [];

      // Add the listener to queue
      const index = topics[topic].push(listener) - 1;

      // Provide handle back for removal of topic
      return {
        remove: () => {
          delete topics[topic][index];
        }
      };
    },
    publish: (topic, info) => {
      // If the topic doesn't exist, or there's no listeners in queue, just leave
      if (!topics.hasOwnProperty(topic)) return;
      const allProperty = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(topic);
      allProperty.forEach((property) => {
        if (property.match(topic)) {
          // Cycle through topics queue, fire!
          topics[topic].forEach((item) => {
            item(info !== undefined ? info : {});
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
})();
```

You will have to modify the code `if (property.match(topic)) {` a bit to satisfy your requirement.